# How many java supported platforms are there?

Tags: java, platform-independence

I am designing a library that is going to use native code, but i plan on making it cross platform.  I was wondering how many different versions i would have to write to support each native implementations such as windows, linux, mac osx.

Comment: How many you choose to support , depends on you I guess !

Comment: But to make it independent on all major platforms that support java?

Comment: Have you had a look at [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)? I believe this is the best you can do...

Comment: What's "major" to you? It depends entirely on who your clients are. If you are in the desktop market, "major" is Windows and perhaps OS X. If you are in the server market, "major" is Linux and Windows, and possibly Solaris and others. If you are in the mainframe market, ...

Comment: Don't forget 32-bit and 64-bit versions for each of these. You may have to do a different one for different versions of OS as well.

Comment: Are you sure what you are trying to do cannot be done in Java? Many things developers assume you can't do in Java, you actually can.  This would avoid needing many multiple versions of JNI libraries.

Comment: I am getting info about batteries and cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is  List of of operating system that Java 7 gives support to [Oracle JDK 7 and JRE 7 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html)